# How to remove columns from CDC (in SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, cdc, change-data-capture

I've enabled CDC on a table, using the code below, and by default it includes all of the columns. There is another way to enable CDC on a table while SPECIFYING the columns (code is given below). However, for me, that's too late - given my CDC was already created and includes ALL of the columns. How do I remove the columns I don't want from the CDC watch list (I searched everywhere in the meta data and couldn't find anything):

```
-- The following enabled the CDC on a table:
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_enable_table 
            @source_schema = N'dbo',
            @source_name = N'TableName',
            @role_name = N'cdc_Admin',  
            @supports_net_changes = 1

-- Now all of the columns are included in the CDC. 

--Alternate (which is too late now given my CDC on table was already created/performed)
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_enable_table      
@source_schema = N'dbo'    , 
@source_name = N'Orders'    , 
@role_name = N'cdc_Admin'    , 
@captured_column_list = N'OrderID,CustomerAccount,Product,SalesPerson'
```

Answer (score 2):

CDC allows you to have up to two capture instances active for a given table at the same time (in order to accommodate schema changes on the underlying table). So, in order to migrate to a new capture instance where you specify the columns (as you do in your second call to `sys.sp_cdc_enable_table`), provide a value for the `@capture_instance` parameter in `sys.sp_cdc_enable_table` and migrate your ETL jobs to use it. Then, once you're sure that nothing is using the old capture instance, drop it using `sys.sp_cdc_disable_table` again providing a value for `@capture_instance` (this time, the old one).

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS I can set the [CDC processing mode] on the CDC data source to 'Net with Update Mask' then see what columns were changed.

You could stage all the data and use the update mask to only process the changes you want to keep.

Comment: This is actually not answering my question.

Comment: It isn't a way to get CDC to stop tracking certain columns, but it does give you access to the meta-data about what was changed. Just an idea for a work around - I think what you are actually asking is not possible.