# How to change the retention period for CDC or put a condition on it (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, cdc, change-tracking, change-data-capture

I'm in a SQL Server 2012 environment, and I have CDC enabled on a table. To sum, the table is used to populate a data warehouse (basically, the content of the table is duplicated elsewhere).

However, I just noticed that we are losing a lot of data because CDC was enabled with the default setting of 3 days. **I know** how to write a query that enables a CDC with a *NEW*/DIFFERENT retention period. But that's not the task, the task is that I must be able to change the current CDC setting. So, is there a way to ***ALTER*** the retention period?

Also, additionally, is there a way to prevent CDC from deleting expired records all in all? meaning, is there a way to implement a flag that prevents the CDC to delete any records UNLESS that record has already been transferred/moved.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sys.sp_cdc_change_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510748.aspx) is what you're looking for to change the retention.

As to your second question, there is no way for CDC to know what rows you've processed and not. So, you have to set your retention period such that you have enough time to process the records that have accumulated since the ETL job last ran. The typical workflow that uses CDC runs on a regular periodic basis (e.g. daily, weekly). So I smell something odd when you say that you're losing data (unless the current retention period is set lower than the time between ETL runs).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the great reference. Just one problem though: "sys.sp_cdc_change_job" does not seem to take a parameter on the table's name. So, does it mean that the retention period can only be set at the database level?

Comment: Also, if you happen to be a CDC expert, would you please have a look at my other question too? That'd be really awesome and I'd be quite thankful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898661/how-to-remove-columns-from-cdc-in-sql-server

Comment: That's correct - the cleanup job is configured and is run at the database (as opposed to the table) level. Again, from a typical CDC workflow, you will usually bring your whole data warehouse up to date as of a specific point in time (as opposed to different tables being at different points in time).

Comment: Thanks so much again. Just one very small question: in  "sys.sp_cdc_change_job" there are two job types ( 'capture' and 'cleanup'). Capture, I'm assuming only deals with recording the changes and 'cleanup' only deals with deleting the "expired" data. SO, what does "retention period" mean in the context of "capture"?  I used this: "SELECT [retention]-- / 60 / 24 AS [Retention_In_Days]
FROM   msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs
WHERE  job_type = N'capture'" .. and I'm getting "0". I'm not sure what that could mean. THanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. I'm blind: it clearly states: "retention is valid only for cleanup jobs.". I apologize for missing this.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the following command can be used (pursuant to the answer above):

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_change_job
  N'cleanup',
  @retention = RetentionTimeInMin --this is a number in minutes
```